# How to change multiple files (gjf) in python

Tags: python, file-rename

So I am trying to change the content in multiple files, the letters Cl to F through out the file.

First to note is that python cannot read the input files I have (gjf) hence I have to convert them to `txt` files first.

I can perform each step individually but when I put it all together and into a loop it doesn't seem to work, can anyone help?

Code:

```
#import modules
import os

#makes a path to CWD and stored as a string
cwd = str( os.getcwd() )

#finds the root, fodlers and and all the files in the cwd and stores them as 
the variable 'roots' dirs and allfiles
for root, dirs, allfiles in os.walk(r'%s'%(cwd)):
continue

#make a collection of gjf files in the folder
my_files=[]
for i in range(0,len(allfiles),1):
     if allfiles[i].endswith('.gjf'):
         my_files.append(allfiles[i])

 else:continue

#makes all gjf files in txt files

for i in range(0,len(my_files),1):
    base= os.path.splitext(my_files[i]) 
    src=my_files[i]
    os.rename(src, base +'.txt')


#replaces all the Cl ligands with F
for i in range(0,len(my_files),1): 
    s = open("my_files[i]").read()
    s = s.replace('Cl', 'F')
    f = open("my_files[i]", 'w')
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to `txt`. Also, use `glob` to get all files of one type.
Check this test example:

Code:

```
from glob import glob


# prepare test file
with open('test.gjf', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Cl foo bar ClbarCl')

# print its content
with open('test.gjf', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print('Before:')
    print(content)

list_of_files = glob('*.gjf')  # get list of all .gjf files

for file in list_of_files:

    # read file:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()

    # replace Cl to F:
    new_content = content.replace('Cl', 'F')

    # Write changes:
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_content)

# Test result
with open('test.gjf', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print('After:')
    print(content)
```

Output:

```
Before:
Cl foo bar ClbarCl
After:
F foo bar FbarF
```